# MySQL get next ZERO-FILLED auto incremented value

Tags: mysql, sql, count, auto-increment

I created a table with a primary key column that is `zero-filled` and having `auto-incremented` value.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TestingDB`.`table1` (
  `id` INT(8) ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

To get the next auto incremented value I use the following statement.

```
SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TestingDB'
AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'table1';
```

but this only get me the next value without the `zero-filled` format, is there a way to show it in `zero-filled` format just like what the primary key does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [LPAD(str,len,padstr)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad):

```
SELECT lpad(`AUTO_INCREMENT`,8,'0')
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TestingDB'
AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'table1';
```